# Do I need to run a loop every time I want to retrieve a particular list of data in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop, dry

UPDATE:

I'm able to run the loop at the very top of the page, but as soon as I exit from the loop (endwhile;) I'm not be able to place my array of data anyway. My data can't be placed anywhere as soon as I close the loop.

So let's say that I will try:

```
<?php /* Template Name: memberplatform */ ?>
<?php $current = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php $temp_query = $wp_query;
query_posts("cat=2&showposts=20");
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
$membername = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'name', true );
$memberemail = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'email', true );
$members = [];
if ( ! empty( $membername ) ) {
    $members[] = '<option value="' . $memberemail . '">' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'name', true) .'</option>';
    echo implode($members);

}
endwhile;
?>
```

and then in the form I'm try to echo my array like that:

```
<select class="drops" name="smallsan">
    <?php echo implode($members); ?>
</select>
```

I can obtain my array within the loop, so in the first place, but I can't populate my dropdown  with my results.

ORIGINAL PROBLEM:

I need to retrieve a list features of people who I've already given a custom field in wordpress, for example, their email or their company name, to display them in an option tag in a select dropdown in a form.

So far so good, but since I need to display two different fields (from a person to another person) I had to run two different loops in this way:

```
<form role="form" class="contactForm contact-form form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Your Name (required)</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select class="drops" name="smallsan">
                    <?php $temp_query = $wp_query; ?>
                    <?php query_posts("cat=2&showposts=20"); ?>
                    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                        <?php 
                        $membername = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'name', true );
                        $memberemail = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'email', true );
                        if ( ! empty( $membername ) ) {
                            echo '<option value="' . $memberemail . '">' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'name', true) .'</option>';
                        }
                        ?>
                        <?php

                        endwhile;
                        ?>
                    </select>
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="controls">
                <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Referring to</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">

                    <select class="drops" name="smallsan">
                        <?php $temp_query = $wp_query; ?>
                        <?php query_posts("cat=2&showposts=20"); ?>
                        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                            <?php 
                            $membername = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'name', true );
                            $memberemail = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'email', true );
                            if ( ! empty( $membername ) ) {
                                echo '<option value="' . $memberemail . '">' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'name', true) .'</option>';
                            }
                            ?>
                            ?>
                            <?php

                            endwhile;
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

and so on.

I tried to run the loop only at the very top to feed both sections, but it didn't work, because in that way I was able to retrieve only a value (not all the members with their email):

```
<form role="form" class="contactForm contact-form form-horizontal">
    <?php $temp_query = $wp_query; ?>
    <?php query_posts("cat=2&showposts=20"); ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <select class="drops" name="smallsan">
            <?php 
            $membername = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'name', true );
            $memberemail = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'email', true );
            if ( ! empty( $membername ) ) {
                echo '<option value="' . $memberemail . '">' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'name', true) .'</option>';
            }
            ?>
            <?php

            endwhile;
            ?>
        </select>
        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="controls">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Referring to</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">

        <select class="drops" name="smallsan">

                <?php 
                $membername = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'name', true );
                $memberemail = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'email', true );
                if ( ! empty( $membername ) ) {
                    echo '<option value="' . $memberemail . '">' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'name', true) .'</option>';
                }
                ?>
                ?>
                <?php

                endwhile;
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Is it right? Is there any other way to avoid to duplicate (DRY) the loop and make the process smother and the code cleaner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need two loops. In the first step you loop once over your posts, get the custom fields and store them formatted as HTML-option in an array. In the second step you multiple print your array.

Here i provide some example-code:

```
<?php query_posts("cat=2&showposts=20"); 
$members = [];
while (have_posts())
{ 
    the_post();
    $membername = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'name', true );
    $memberemail = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'email', true );


    if ( ! empty( $membername ) ) {
        $members[] = '<option value="' . $memberemail . '">' . get_post_meta($post->ID, 'name', true) .'</option>';
    }
}

?>

<form role="form" class="contactForm contact-form form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="controls">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Your Name (required)</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select class="drops" name="smallsan">
                    <?php echo implode($members); ?>
                </select>
                <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Referring to</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">

                <select class="drops" name="smallsan">
                    <?php echo implode($members); ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I tried to use your code but it didn't work, as soon as I close the loop it will print only one result, so I tried to end it at the very end of the code, but still it won't work

Comment: try to var_dump($members).

Comment: I found the problem in your code:
The array $members= []; has to be placed outside the loop before while!

If you're gonna change your answer I'm gonna mark it!

Comment: thanks for the hint i didn't noticed, but you are complete right, the inizialisation of "$members" should be outside of the loop